# Microsoft Word - How to reduce text size in all styles

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts, styles, microsoft-word-2016

Using Microsoft Word for Mac 2016, I want to reduce the size for every style by one increment. For example, Heading 1, Heading 2, and Normal default to 16, 13, and 12 respectively. I would like them to be 14, 12, and 11.

Is there a way to do this without manually editing every single style?

Comment: You *might* be able to do it in VBA.

Comment: Manually editing every single style is faster than writing a VBA code to do it. There are not that many styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not.

There is no built-in method of modifying all of the styles known to Word in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with keyboard shortcuts.

- In order to increase the font size, you need to press
  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>.
- In order to
  decrease the font size, you need to press
  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>.

**Edit: Just realized that you are using Word on Mac. You have to press** <kbd>⌘</kbd> **instead of** <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. <kbd>[Some keyboard shortcuts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-for-mac-3256d48a-7967-475d-be81-a6e3e1284b25#bkmk_formatchara16)</kbd>


If you select some text with different font sizes, Word will decrease/increase the font size of all of it.

**Important Note:

The font size will not increase/decrease by 1 point every time. For example, if you press** <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>**, it will set the font size of each character to the preceding value in the list.**
**Similarly, if you press** <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>**, it will set the font size of each character to the next value in the list.**

[image]

**Edit 2: You will have to do this every time you use a Style.**

Comment: the OP wants to reduce **the styles' sizes**, not the normal text font sizes